# Background issues

Tags: html, css, background

I need to create a small website that can be opened and functional in a single file. I can't quite figure out how to get an image background to show up. I have my image in `Desktop/assignment/Website-Background.jpg`. I have tried a bunch of different ways to get it to work, but it just wont. My current code is:

```
 body{
    height: 100%;
}

.bg { 
    background-image: url("Website-Background.jpg");
    height: 100%; 
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

And I have tried also tried

```
body {
  background-image: url("Website-Background.jpg");
}
```

Can somebody point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: and the image is in the same folder as your .html file?

Comment: where exactly is `Website-Background.jpg` store?

Comment: just do `background-image: url("Desktop/assignment/Website-Background.jpg");`  ?

Comment: put the correct path before the image with respect to your html file name in url...

Comment: yes @StefanDelport it is.

Comment: Have you tried specifying your html and body height to 100%?  html, body{
  height: 100%;
}

Answer (score 0):

First in your browser press F12 and youll see if the image is being called or not in the console window, Then if it is being called and there is no error then maybe set a height of 200px and see if the image shows up.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the image and your html document in the same folder and your code will work like a charm...You will have to change nothing in code to make it work..

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe you are indicating the location of the image properly. Remember for CSS, you have to back out of folders and go into others to find the file. Where is your HTML file? You may have to back out of its location and into your assignment folder.

If you are backing out:

```
body {
  background:url("../assignment/Website-background.jpg");
  background-size:cover;
}
```

If you simply have to go deeper into your folder:

```
body {
  background:url("assignment/Website-background.jpg");
  background-size:cover;
}
```

Comment: My html file is in the same folder as the image, Desktop/Assignment

Comment: Have you tried
 body { background:url("Website-Background.jpg"); background-size:cover; }

Comment: Just did, didn't work. I think my wysiwyg may be causing issues.

Answer (score 0):

Just a side note that if you "really" want to have your website as a single file (meaning that background image is another file), you can encode your image into base64 via some tool ([like](https://www.base64-image.de/)) and then have it in your file.